# split a string and pass the first argument to a function from elif block using python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

Can I split a string into 2 parts and pass the first part to another function inside an "elif" block. Here i want to pass the date part as an parameter to another function but only from "elif" block.

```
Input :
    row[0] = '04/07/2018 CA Enrollment Fee'
```

I tried as below but no success. Please suggest.

```
def parse(row):
  if ....:
     ....

  elif ((a, b = row[0].split(' ', 1)) and validate_fees(a)):
     ...
  else:
     retunrn EnrollmentFailed()

def validate_fees(enrollmentdate):
  try:
    en_date = datetime.strptime(enrollmentdate, "%d/%m/%Y")
    return en_date is not None
  except ValueError:
    return False
```

Comment: Something like this `validate_fees(row[0].split(' ', 1)[0])`

Comment: If you are using Python3.8 you can look into the new assignment expressions. This may help to write this code a bit nicer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do as you say, you can pass the first part of the split directly to your validate function:

```
if ...:
    ...
elif validate_fees(row[0].split(' ', 1)[0]):
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you make a unit test for your problem:

```
# file: test_my_function.py

def test_split_and_pass_first_arg():
    s = "10/11/2018 blah blah"
    assert(my_function(s) == date(10, 11, 2018))
```

You can run this with e.g. `pytest test_my_function.py`  (cf. https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/)
This will make debugging unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

yes,

**split() method returns a list**

so a,b=row.split(' ',1) will give an error
the right way will be :-

```
    list_a=row.split(' ',1)
    print(list_a)
```

***output:***

['21/3/2019', 'Enrollment Fee']

to access the date part you may use index of the list i.e

```
    list_a[0]
```

***output:***

'21/3/2019'

here is a reference link that talks about split() method in more depth
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python3/string_split.htm